# Slow MySQL query with "WHERE [tinyint] ORDER BY ID"

Tags: mysql, performance, entity-framework-core

I have a table with a boolean-like field "Blocked" (as non-nullable tinyint) for which I have an index.

Running

```
  SELECT `p`.`Id`
  FROM `ProjectTasks` AS `p`
  WHERE `p`.`Blocked` > 0
  ORDER BY `p`.`Id`
```

or

```
  SELECT `p`.`Id`
  FROM `ProjectTasks` AS `p`
  WHERE `p`.`Blocked`
```

are both fast (MySql Workbench shows 0.000 seconds).

But running

```
  SELECT `p`.`Id`
  FROM `ProjectTasks` AS `p`
  WHERE `p`.`Blocked`
  ORDER BY `p`.`Id`
```

is very slow (0.5 seconds when returning ~50 out of 50.000 entries).

Using EXPLAIN shows that the Index is not used in the latter query.

Unfortunately I cannot just add the `> 0`  because the query is generated by EF Core. Is there anything I can change to the index so it gets used with the last version of the query?

Comment: You can actually tell EF core to define indexes for you with selected columns, this will make sure your query will use index when certain columns are queried. Have a look at docs.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=data-annotations

Comment: Create an index by `(Blocked, Id)` and use ```WHERE `p`.`Blocked` = 1 ORDER BY `p`.`Id` ``` (if it is "boolean-like NOT NULL" then the values in it are 0 and 1 only).

Comment: @MaulikParmar I have `modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectTask>().HasIndex(pt => new { pt.Blocked });` already (and just added another index with Blocked,Id as well), but it's not used.
@Akina I have added the index, but with `WHERE p.Blocked` it's not used. I cannot add the `= 1` because the query is generated by EF Core.

Comment: `protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectTask>()
        .HasIndex(pt => new { pt.id, pt.Blocked });
}`  Can you confirm your db has the index defined? If not just migrate model, recreate so it actually creates the index. Indexes get created at the same time when table is created or with migrations. Make sure it's there, also mysql supports boolean type, why not use itn there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Also slow queries can be of multiple reasons, may be low io or memory, small page size etc. If you can confirm indexes are there and used then we can narrow down on what's causing problem.

Comment: Which Provider do you use? Not EF Core generates SQL but concrete EF Core provider. If you use official Oracle's MySql provider, it can be mistake... There is `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` which should work better.

Comment: If index is not used, create a new index with two fields, blocked and od, in this order. BTW what is the purpose of where without condtion? Does ot mean not null?

Comment: (1) What's the situation if you use `WHERE 'p'.'Blocked' <> 0` in the raw SQL query? (2) Please provide EFC version, the provider used and its version (see  the comment by @Svyatoslav)

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and show us the `EXPLAINs`.  And `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`  Perhaps only 1% of us know EF Core; talking SQL will help you get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

*ORDER BY* clause can also greatly benefit from using index. Is your p.Id field indexed? If not, I recommend you to create an index on *p.Id*.

Answer (score 0):

If EF Core cannot generate the desired SQL, does it at least allow you to write "raw" SQL?  If neither, then jettison the framework; it is getting in the way.

```
WHERE Blocked = 1
ORDER BY Id
```

together with

```
INDEX(Blocked, Id)
```

can be optimized by MySQL.  Virtually any other query and index cannot.